# jq - add prefix to values on array

Tags: arrays, json, export-to-csv, jq

input json:

```
[
{
  "login": "u1",
  "name": "u1",
  "role": "User",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "name": "G1"
    },
    {
      "id": "1235",
      "name": "G2"
    }
  ],
  "created": "2020-05-11 11:06"
},
{
  "login": "u2",
  "name": "u2",
  "role": "User",
  "groups": null,
  "created": "2020-05-11 11:06"
}
]
```

I use following filter to get users and groups they are member of:

```
$ jq -r '
  .[]
  | [.login,
     .name,
     ( if .groups == null 
       then "grp:-" 
       else (del(.groups[]
             | select(.name=="All Users"))
            | [.groups[].name] | join("|")) 
       end )]
  | @tsv' json
```

```
u1      u1      G1|G2
u2      u2      grp:-
```

How to add `grp:` prefix for each found group?

Expected output would be:

```
u1      u1      grp:G1|grp:G2
u2      u2      grp:-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+` to concatenate strings:

```
jq -r '.[]
       | [.login,.name,(
           if .groups == null
           then "grp:-"
           else (
               del(.groups[] | select(.name=="All Users"))
               | ["grp:" + .groups[].name]
#                 ~~~~~~~~
               | join("|")
           )
           end
      )]
      | @tsv'
```

You can even avoid specifying "grp:" twice, but you need to return an array from the *then* branch, too:

```
jq -r '.[]
       | [.login, .name, (
           (
               if .groups == null
               then ["-"]
               else (
                   del(.groups[] | select(.name=="All Users"))
                   | [.groups[].name]
               )
               end
           )
           | map("grp:" + .)
           | join("|")
       )]
       | @tsv'
```

*Update*:
Getting inspiration from *peak* I guess this produces the output you wanted:

```
jq -r '.[]
        | .groups //= []
        | del(.groups[] | select(.name=="All Users"))
        | .groups[0] //= {name: "-"}
        | [.login, .name, ( ["grp:" + (.groups[].name)] | join("|") ) ]
        | @tsv'
```

Comment: I found one issue when groups array has only "All Users" which I delete - then instead "grp:-" I get empty output. Here sample input for such case: [{"login":"u1","name":"u1","role":"User","groups":[{"id":"1234","name":"G1"},{"id":"1235","name":"G1"}],"created":"2020-05-11 11:06"},{"login":"u2","name":"u2","role":"User","groups":null,"created":"2020-05-11 11:06"},{"login":"u3","name":"u3","role":"User","groups":[{"id":"1234","name":"All Users"}],"created":"2020-05-11 11:06"}]

Comment: @Chris - Does the variant solution I posted just now handle the edge case appropriately from your point of view?

Comment: @peak: I modified it a bit and I think it produces the expected output now. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly shorter and perhaps tidier variant of the solution already given. It has the advantage of handling the edge case mentioned in a comment elsewhere on this page.

```
  .[]
  | .groups //= [{name: "-"}]
  | [.login,
     .name,
     (del(.groups[] | select(.name=="All Users"))
     | ["grp:" + (.groups[].name)] | join("|")) 
    ]
  | @tsv
```

#### Simpler still

````
  .groups //= [{name: "-"}]
  | .groups |= map(select( .name != "All Users") )
  | [.login, .name,
     (.groups | map("grp:" + .name) | join("|")) ]
  | @tsv```
````